# Install Ruby 2.4.1 in windows within corporate proxy. MSYS2 update fails

Tags: ruby, msys2, rubyinstaller

I am using ruby installer [rubyinstaller-2.4.1-2-x64.exe](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives/) to install `ruby 2.4.1 on windows 10`. It is successful and at the end of install `MSYS2` installation is triggered. It is also successful. But `MSYS2 system update` fails with the following error.

```
mingw32.sig      96.0   B  93.8K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
error: mingw32: signature from "Alexey Pavlov (Alexpux) <alexpux@gmail.com>" is invalid
error: failed to update mingw32 (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

Any workaround to fix this?

Note: The same installation package works perfectly in my home network. So I guess it is something to do with the corporate firewall.

Comment: Do you mind giving a download link from where you are installing, rather linking the file itself

Comment: @gates Updated the link. https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I somehow made it work, by going through various SO answers. Following are the set of actions that made it work.

1. Set proxy in env variables

   `setx http_proxy="http://proxy.server.address:port"
    setx https_proxy="http://proxy.server.address:port"
    setx ftp_proxy="http://proxy.server.address:port"
    setx rsync_proxy="http://proxy.server.address:port"`
2. Delete all files from C:\msys64\var\lib\pacman\sync
3. Open C:\msys64\mingw64.exe and run the command `pacman -Syy`
4. Since `pacman` is working now, I returned to the original `ruby installer 2` process. It worked!

   `ridk install`

   `1 - MSYS2 base installation - Completed Already
   2 - MSYS2 system update -Successful now after proxy update
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain -Successful now after proxy update`