# ERROR: Error installing yajl-ruby:

Tags: ruby, windows

Please help... i was tryed all ruby versions and have the same error.

!!!!THIS IS WINDOWS!!!!

```
    gem install yajl-ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing yajl-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.3.1/ext/yajl
C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20171206-2828-1djbqt4.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.3.1/ext/yajl
make "DESTDIR=" clean
"make" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

current directory: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.3.1/ext/yajl
make "DESTDIR="
"make" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/yajl-ruby-1.3.1/gem_make.out
```

google does not help me also.

**UPDATE:** the problem was fixed by installing kali linux.
the problem was the windows. 
thank you all.
i lost my day on it.

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Did you install the [devkit](https://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the issue is due to msys2 not being installed properly. Check by updating msys2 by running `ridk install`

check here for more info on successfully ypdating msys2 [Install Ruby 2.4.1 in windows within corporate proxy. MSYS2 update fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328474/install-ruby-2-4-1-in-windows-within-corporate-proxy-msys2-update-fails)